# Connection lost during emit (socket.io)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

What happens if the client tries to emit a message to the server, **while he doesn't have a connection** (like lost wifi) ?

I observed that it sometimes **emits again** as soon as the connection is stable and sometimes **it doesn't.** I don't get any errors, I just observed on the server that the emitted messages from the client sometimes get delivered to the server and sometimes just a few, and sometimes none. It is very inconsistent.

What is the mechanism and how can I work with it properly?

That is my client:

```
import openSocket from "socket.io-client"; 
const socket = openSocket("http://192.168.0.12:5000")
const message = {content: "hello"}
socket.emit("new message", message);
```

That is my server:

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

http.listen(5000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:5000');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){

  socket.on('new message', (msg) =>{
    console.log(msg);
  });
});
```

Comment: connections will timeout after some time, triggering the "disconnect" event.

Comment: You should precise your question if you want a relevant answer, what are your socket settings (you should add some code to the question)? Do you have errors when "sometimes it doesn't"? is "reconnection" set to true? etc..

Comment: @Kaddath I edited my post. I don't know where I should set the reconnection? Also it automatically reconnects as soon as the connection is back online, but it doesn't ALWAYS resend the emitted messages during offline time.

Comment: By "just a few" you mean that only a part of the message arrives (i never had this case)? Btw I fear you have to handle those cases yourself. Client and server should both have a `on('disconnect', function...)` to detect when it happens. Also, the server should probably acknowledge the message reception, and if this doesn't happen, re-send it manually, something like that..

Comment: @Kaddath yes exactly. Let's say I send a message 50 times during a connection lost. Then I turned on the wifi again and the messages were automatically send to the server as soon as the connection is back online. But with every try I do that test, the server sometimes receive all messages after the connection lost, sometimes just 10, sometimes none. it is very inconsistent. And yes I was thinking that too, to handle the messages manually. But the problem is that one message can accidentally send multiple times...

Comment: Because when I have a mechanism that resends the ones that are not acknowledged, and socket.io resends them automatically again as soon as the connection is online again, it sends them 2 times.

Comment: Yes, because you should probably send only one, then if you detect connection is lost, wait for reconnection (plus a little delay in case the server is answering the already sent one) before you try to send another one.. Those messages should probably hold something like a timestamp so you can indentify which one is answered or not

Comment: yes exactly that was my idea too. But when socket.io sends it (sometimes) automatically and sometimes it doesn't, it is hard to control it. Or is there a way to completely turn off the setting in socket.io, to say that it should only try to emit it once and if the server doesn't answer, it is up to me as a programmer to implement to logic? I didn't find this option, because I couldn't figure out how socket.io really handles this situation normally...

Comment: I shall give a depper look, as it interests me for our code too (haven't noticed if it happens for us too, our system is complex and may respond favorably to these cases).. but from the [last message here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java/issues/322) there seems to be an emission buffer (the guy looks at the java code, but it may be the same in NodeJS)

Comment: ah yes that is exactly the issue that I am facing too. However in that post, he also doesn't solve it. I really wonder why it is not "common", so there is something in the docs in it. In my case it is really crucial, because as I am writing a chat app, I don't want the message to get delivered twice or none.